# Fastest way to find a value from another data set (VBA) (code speedup)

Tags: vba, excel

I have two datasets that are both within a worksheet, call them Data and IBES. The code checks whether the 6 variables are the same in each dataset and then writes the value from a specific column to the other dataset. To find this value the code runs through 288503 lines which is dramatically slow.

My question is, how to speedup this code?

Thank you very much!

```
Public Function GetRightValue()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


For i = 2 To 1511           'Loop over all values from total dataset
        For j = 2 To 288503      'Loop over all values from IBES file
            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 1) Then
                If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 6) Then
                    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 10) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 9) Then
                        If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 13) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 11) Then
                            If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 7) Then
                                If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 14).Text = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 13).Text Then
                                    Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 12) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 10).Text
                                    Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 18) = Worksheets("IBES").Cells(j, 16).Text
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Function
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113741/76246 and Code Review is a more appropriate site for the question

Comment: your code makes little sense , your not looping  288503  , your looping 435,928,033!   ?!    Use "Find" at least! or add a helper column with all 6 values concatenated, then use , vlookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary. Add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your project (`Tools/References` in the VBA editor) and try:

```
Public Function GetRightValue()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim d As New Dictionary, k As String, c As Collection, v As Variant

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

With Worksheets("Data")
    For i = 1 To 1511
        k = Join(Array(.Cells(i, 3).Value, .Cells(i, 7).Value, _
                 .Cells(i, 10).Value, .Cells(i, 13).Value, .Cells(i, 8).Value, _
                 .Cells(i, 14).Value, .Cells(i, 12).Value, .Cells(i, 18).Value), "#")
        If Not d.Exists(k) Then
            Set c = New Collection
            d.Add k, c
        End If
        d.Item(k).Add i
    Next i
End With

With Worksheets("IBES")
    For j = 2 To 288503
        k = Join(Array(.Cells(j, 1).Value, .Cells(j, 6).Value, _
                 .Cells(j, 9).Value, .Cells(j, 11).Value, .Cells(j, 7).Value, _
                 .Cells(j, 13).Value, .Cells(j, 10).Value, .Cells(i, 16).Value), "#")
        If d.Exists(k) Then
            For Each v In d.Item(k)
                Worksheets("Data").Cells(v, 12) = .Cells(j, 10)
                Worksheets("Data").Cells(v, 18) = .Cells(j, 16)
            Next v
        End If
    Next j
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Function
```

Comment: I like this answer as well as my own, classy :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Set your worksheets to variables e.g.

```
Dim ws1, ws2 as Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Data")
Set ws2 = Sheets("IBES")

If ws1.Cells(i, 3) = ws2.Cells(j, 1) Then... etc
```

2) It may be quicker to line up all those If statements on one line with And statements

3) If one of your Ifs is false then move to the next iteration. This saves a tiny bit over exiting child Ifs e.g.

```
For x = 1 to 10
   If myCondion then
      doStuff
   Else
      GoTo xLine
   End If

xLine:
Next x
```

4) Sometimes it may be quicker to put the datasets into arrays and then compare the array items e.g.

```
myArray = Range("A1:A10")
myOtherArray = myOtherSheet.Range("A1:A10")

If myArray(0,1) = myOtherArray(0 + whatever, 1) Then...
```

Hope this helps